# javascript forEach add new object to array return null

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am populating my array using some function like this:

```
    const items = [
            {name : 'original', count: 'one'}, 
            {name: 'copy', count: 'two'}, 
            {name: 'redundant', count: 'three'}];

    let myitems = [];
    items.forEach(function (k) {
      myitems[k.name] = myFunction(k.count);
    }, this);
    console.log('final nurls: ', myitems);
```

the **console.log** returns empty!

but when i do this:

```
items.forEach(function (k) {
  let item = myFunction(k.count)
  myitems.push(item);
}, this);
```

then a console log returns the expected results.

why is the first version returning empty?

Comment: `myitems[k.name]` does not seem right for an array. It would work for an object though.

Comment: try `let myitems = {};` - learn the difference between  Objects and Arrays

Comment: There is a function for this task called `map`: `let myitems = items.map(k => myFunction(k.count));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you defined "myitems" as an array, it cannot contain key-value pairs.

```
myitems[k.name] = X;
```

would like to do just that, while

```
myitems.push(X);
```

is adding new items to the array.